# With a pandas dataframe, how can I set a background color for both levels of a multi-index when outputting to the body of an email as HTML?

Tags: html, pandas, email, formatting, jupyter

I have created a pandas dataframe and set a background color for the multiindex columns with the styles method. When i output it to Jupyter, both levels of the multiindex columns have the background color. But when i export it email, the background color shows on the first level only. Is there any way to color both levels of the multiindex columns when exporting to email?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=3)

columns = list("ABCD")
columns = list(zip(['HEADER'] * 4, columns))             
#[('HEADER', 'A'), ('HEADER', 'B'), ('HEADER', 'C'), ('HEADER', 'D')]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns, names=['first', 'second'])  

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4),index=dates,columns=columns)

styles = [{'props':[("font-family", "Calibri")]}, {
       'selector': 'th',
       'props': [
           ('background-color', 'yellow'),
           ('text-align','center')
       ]}]


s = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)

html = s.hide_index().render()
with open("html_c.html","w") as fp:
   fp.write(html)

#to display in a jupyter notebook
display(HTML(html))
```

it outputs correctly in Jupyter...

[image]

...but when I export it to the body of an email...

```
import win32com.client as win32   
#send email with html in body
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = #*email address*
mail.Subject = "HTML TEST"
mail.HTMLBody = html
mail.Send()
```

...I get this output, with no background color on the second level index of columns:

[image]

many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this myself. I had to add rowspan="2" to the header selector in styles.